# Why aren't there any online AC: Brotherhood games?

Tags: ps3, assassins-creed-brotherhood

Right now I'm trying to play an online game in AC: Brotherhood, and have been for half an hour, but the system won't find any. I'm playing it on PS3 in the Netherlands. Could something be wrong on my end or is it really this unpopular? Could the impending release of WoW Cataclysm have anything to do with it?

Comment: @Fabian That second one would've totally been appropriate if Cataclysm turned out to be the culprit!

Comment: @Grace You can revert it if it turns out that Blizzard is to blame. ♪

Comment: Woe to anyone who tries to release a video game this December, especially a multiplayer game. However the OP might just be having network problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The game started out being unpopular. It should work now. I play Assassins Creed Brotherhood and it works fine for me. Try again and it should work.

Comment: Yeah I noticed it was a lot easier when I last tried recently.